# Configuring the NetBeans IDE for C/C++

Tags: c++, macos, netbeans

I am trying to configure Netbeans 7.4 on my mac OSX so that I want to do some unit Testing on my program

I found a resource

https://netbeans.org/community/releases/71/cpp-setup-instructions.html

but it just says

Macintosh OS X

NetBeans IDE has been tested with the following compilers and tools:

```
Software or Resource Version          Tested Description 
gcc                   4.2.1           GNU C compiler in Mac OS X 10.6
g++                   4.2.1           GNU C++ compiler in Mac OS X 10.6
gdb                   6.3.5           GNU debugger in Mac OS X 10.6
make                  3.81            GNU make in Mac OS X 10.6
```

Install the following packages that are provided with your Macintosh OS X:

```
Xcode
X11
```

what I don't understand is the resource telling to use Xcode instead of netbeans?
but I need to use netbeans for my unit testing?

and also I tried creating a simple program but it's has a error message

```
cannot find include file <iostream>
```

basically not just for

```
<iostream>
```

but all my #include libraries.

I right click on my project file in netbeans and went to C++ compliers to take a look and found that the "Include Directories and Headers" is blank.

do I have to install additional stuff to solve the error?

Comment: You need to install the command-line tools, so use `xcode-select --install` to install it. Note however that the apple tools use a different compilation/debugging backend to `gdb` (it's called `clang/llvm` & `lldb`), so you should probably install `gdb` using one of the packaging mechanisms (such as [`macports`](http://www.macports.org) or [`brew`](http://brew.io)